# NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

```
 NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook

  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

  Rails.root: /home/krishna/picer
  Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

  app/models/user.rb:13:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
  app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `facebook'
```

This is my user.rb code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable:omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :omniauthable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
data = access_token['extra']['user_hash']
if user = User.find_by_email(data["email"])
  user
else # Create a user with a stub password.
  User.create(:email => data["email"], :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
  end
end

 def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  super.tap do |user|
    if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]  ["extra"]["user_hash"]
    user.email = data["email"]
   end
  end
 end
end
```

And omniauth callbacks controller code

```
 class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def facebook
 # You need to implement the method below in your model
 @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
 end
end

def passthru
  render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
 end

end
```

I am getting error line four user.rb I used a example for this https://github.com/ryanatwork/devise-omniauth

Comment: access_token['extra']['user_hash'] is probably nil, can you log it to console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the user email with `access_token['info']['email']` instead of `access_token['extra']['user_hash']['email']`.

I don't think the data in `access_token['extra']` follows a convention like the rest, so you should be extra careful and test if the property you're trying to access exists. It's not that important if you only have one provider, but it is if you have several of them.